# Content of NextSibling not being printed out

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have this piece of code, and I can't figure out why it's not printing out the content of the next  container.

```
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
     doc.Load("Billing106.htm");

     foreach (HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(., ' SEMANTIC:')]"))
     {
        richTextBox1.Text += "SC: " + div.NextSibling.InnerText.ToString();
     }
```

I have several entries in an HTML file as followed:

```
    <div style="top: 232px; left: 332px;" class="S4"> SEMANTIC:</div>
    <div style="top: 233px; left: 377px;" class="S3"> SBR02 specifies the relationship to the person insured.</div>
```

I can't check for the  class="S3" as there are multiple items using the same class.

if someone has an idea how to make it work, it would be greatly appreciated, as I want to go home and enjoy my weekend, I'll be sure to send you a e-Beer, hehe.

Note: It does print out 3 times     "SC: " it occurs 3 times in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the next sibling of this DIV element is not the other DIV, but the text between the two DIVs (yes, they are nodes too). If you want the next sibling of DIV type, this is what you should do:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
     doc.Load("Billing106.htm");

 foreach (HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(., ' SEMANTIC:')]"))
 {
    richTextBox1.Text += "SC: " + div.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::div").InnerText.ToString();
 }
```

See here for an explanation of XPATH axes: [XPATH Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, that surely did the trick, I can't believe it was something so simple! :D

Comment: I have one other question for you though, how would I go around getting the "innertext" for multiple div's under the "Semantic" div?

Comment: Here is a link of a longer example of HTML http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=zjQhFSPz

I would like to save all information in a SQL database

Comment: you could do a SelectNodes instead of SelectSingleNode